# Authenticate user with j_security_check

Tags: java, authentication, j-security-check

I am working on one application. It is using j_security_check to authenticate user.
It is working fine. It authenticates user. I want to display login failure page. For this i am using

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
   <form-login-config>
       <form-login-page>/webpages/login.jsf</form-login-page>
       <form-error-page>/webpages/loginerror.jsf</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

but loginerror.jsf is not getting displayed. application shows HTTP error 403.

My question is where should i change to display loginerror.jsf page

thanks

Answer (score 1):

403 means forbidden.  Have you configured your security mechanism to allow access to the loginerror page?

Comment: It's not Spring Security, it's security options of Servlet specification. However, the point of the answer seems to be right.

Comment: @axtavt, thanx for pointing that out.  Ive only ever used spring security, so for some reason thats where my brain always starts ;)